# SQLServer Maintenance Plan Cleanup misses files by minutes

Tags: backup, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a set of maintenance plans in place that perform a full backup weekly, and once complete, delete any .bak's that are a week old. This is important, because the DBs are very large and disk space for backups is limited.

Usually this works fine, but, the last two weeks, the prior week .bak were not deleted.

From what I can see, this weeks backup completed in 2-minutes less time than the prior run, so the file creation date for the prior week .bak, is **just 2 minutes shy of being 1 week old at the time the job ran**.

This seems like a fatal flaw in the system, so I'm looking for ideas for addressing the issue. How do you folks handle this?

Comment: Well, the obvious (and easiest) solution would be to purge backups older than 6 days, rather than backups older than 7 days.

Comment: My concern there, is that after the incremental backup time on Saturday, we loose the ability to restore should anything untoward occur, until after Sunday nights full backup time. It is definitely an option, but I was hoping for something a little cleaner.

Comment: Missing the point.  You need to set your threshold for deleting the old databases to be between backup jobs. 84 hours (6.5 days), for example.